# Find remainder of $F_n$ when divided by $5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $\{ F_n\}$ be the sequence of numbers defined by $F_1=1=F_2;\, F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$. Let $f_n$ be the remainder left when $F_n$ is divided by $5$. Then $f_{2000}$ equals
>
> **(A)** $0$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ **(B)** $1$   $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ **(C)** $2$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ **(D)** $3$

I found that $F(1)=1$, $F(2)=1$, $F(3)=2$, $F(4)=3$, $F(5)=5$, $F(6)=8$, $F(7)=13$, $F(8)=21$, $F(9)=34$, and $F(10)=55$. But I need a systematic pattern to find $F_n$.

Comment: Look at the *remainders* of the fibonacci sequence upon division by $5$ (aka "modulo $5$"). Then you will see that it repeats. (It must: any finite recursion relation solution defined on a finite set must eventually repeat.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now the pattern for the remainder is,
$f_{1}=1$, $f_{2}={1}$, $f_{3}={2}$, $f_{4}={3}$ now we have $f_{5}=0$. So this is our first zero. If you proceed in this manner you will see that $f_{10}=0$ and $f_{15}=0$ and so on. So, $f_{2000}=0$.

Comment: This is a valid observation, but not a rigorous proof. Note that $F_6\equiv 3$, $F_7\equiv 3$ etc, so the remainders mod $5$ do **not** repeat every $5$ numbers. (In fact, the cycle length is $20$).

Answer (score 4):

$\rm{\bf Hint}\ \ \  mod\ 5\!:\,\ F_{k}\!\equiv\color{#0A0}0\:\Rightarrow\:F_{k+5}\!\equiv\color{#C00}0\ \ \ by\ \ \  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\rm k&\rm k\!+\!1 &\rm k\!+\!2 &\rm k\!+\!3 &\rm k\!+\!4 &\rm k\!+\!5\\ \hline
 \color{#0A0}0&\rm n       &\rm    n    &\rm    2n   &\rm       3n  &\rm \color{#C00}0 \\\hline\end{array}$

Comment: A nice observation!

Answer (score 2):

$$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}=F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}+F_{n-2}=2F_{n-2}+F_{n-1}$$
$$=2(F_{n-3}+F_{n-4})+F_{n-3}=3F_{n-3}+2F_{n-4}$$

$$=3(F_{n-4}+F_{n-5})+2F_{n-4}=5F_{n-4}+3F_{n-5}$$

$$\text{ So,} F_n\equiv 3F_{n-5}\pmod 5 $$

As $F_1=F_2=1\implies F_0=F_2-F_1=0\equiv0\pmod 5$

$\implies 5\mid F_n$ if $5\mid n$

---

Alternatively,  from Lemma#$5$ of [this](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/4-3/halton.pdf) , $F_n\mid F_m \iff n\mid m\text{ or } n=2$ for $m\ge n\ge 1$

We find $F_2=F_1=1,F_3=2,F_4=3, F_5=5$

So, $F_5\mid F_m \iff 5\mid m$ for $m\ge1$

Comment: Wish I could thank somebody for pinpointing the mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! Your explanations are always complete and self-explaining.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Show by induction that $F_n \equiv 2n3^n\mod 5$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have all these nice answers here, I thought I'd provide the obvious solution:
\begin{align}f_{2000}=F_{2000}\bmod 5=&42246963333923048787067256023414827825798528402506\\
&81098010280137314308584370130707224123599639141511\\
&08844608753890960360764019471164359602927198331259\\
&87373262535558026069915859152294924539049987222567\\
&95316982874482472992263901833716778060607011615497\\
&88671987985831146887087626459736908672288402365442\\
&22952433479644801395153495629720876526560695298064\\
&99841977448720155612802665404554171717881930324025\\
&204312082516817125\bmod 5=0\end{align}

(It's a lot easier to use $5\mid F_5\mid F_{5\cdot200}$ though.)