# How is $f_{2000}$ equals $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(F_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be the sequence of numbers defined by $F_1=1=F_2$; $F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}$ for $n\geq2.$ Let $f_n$ be the remainder left when $F_n$ is divided by $5$. Then $f_{2000}$ equals $0$.

**My Try:**
$F_3=2,F_4=3,F_5=5,F_6=8,F_7=13,\dots$

Then I subtracted $S_n=1+1+2+3+5+8+13+\dots$ from $S_n=1+1+2+3+5+8+13+\dots$ and got $0=1+0+1+1+2+3+5+8+13+\dots$ (Sorry, I can't $\LaTeX$ that properly.)
 But, how to go further? How can we reach to conclusion that $f_{2000}=0$?

Comment: You may want to look up the Pisano period: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344716/find-remainder-of-f-n-when-divided-by-5)

Comment: Using this(http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/FibonacciGCD.shtml) or http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20004.5.shtml,  $$F_{5n}$$ is divisible by $$F_5=5$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, Fibonacci sequence.

The trick here is to take everything modulo $5$, denoted as $\mod{5}$. In other words, write all of the terms in the sequence as the remainder if they were to be divided by $5$. For example:
$$
9 \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
5 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
3+8 = 11 \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
3+8 \equiv 3+3 = 6 \equiv 1 \pmod 5
$$
Notice how by using modular arithmetic, it doesn't matter whether we do modulo before or after. This is convenient because we don't have to actually evaluate each term of the sequence to find the next term modulo $5$.

You also may be wondering why we used $\equiv$ instead of $=$. The $=$ implies equality, which means two things are exactly the same. However, when we say that two numbers are equivalent ($\equiv$) modulo $5$, we're saying that they are both related in some way (in this case,  modulo $5$). They're related, but not exactly *equal*.

So now we write the sequence $\mod 5$.
$$
F_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
F_2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
F_3 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \\
F_4 \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \\
F_5 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
F_6 \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \\
F_7 \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \\
F_8 \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
F_9 \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
F_{10} \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
F_{11} \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
F_{12} \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
F_{13} \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \\
F_{14} \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \\
F_{15} \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
F_{16} \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \\
F_{17} \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \\
F_{18} \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
F_{19} \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
F_{20} \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
F_{21} \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
F_{22} \equiv 1 \pmod 5
$$
You may notice that the sequence repeats. $F_1 \equiv F_{21} \pmod 5$, $F_2 \equiv F_{22} \pmod 5$, $F_3 \equiv F_{23} \pmod 5$, etc. Notice the difference of $20$ in the indices.

This means that for all $a$ and $b$, $F_a \equiv F_b \pmod 5$ if $a \equiv b \pmod {20}$.

Since $2000 \equiv 0 \equiv 20 \pmod {20}$, $F_{2000} \equiv F_{20} \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Be wary not to get confused. When we were finding the remainder by dividing by $5$, we were dividing the *terms of the sequence* by $5$. The *indices* are what we divide by $20$ to get the same equivalence of the terms, because the sequence modulo $5$ repeats every $20$ terms. Coincidentally, every fifth term of the Fibonacci sequence is also divisible by $5$, but make sure you don't get confused between the two.

Answer (score 4):

You are just being asked to prove that the $2000$th Fibonacci number is a multiple of $5$.

From the recurrence relation $F_{k}=F_{k-1}+F_{k-2}$ we find that $F_{5(k+1)}=5F_{5k+1}+3F_{5k}$. Since $F_5=5$, we can show by induction that $5$ divides $F_{5k}$ for all $k\ge 1$.

Comment: A nice alternative to writing out the first $20$ terms modulo $5$!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: work modulo $5$ directly. Your $f_n$ will be *periodic*.

Comment: Thank you. Will you please also provide the method to find $F_{2000}$? Also how are we guaranteed that $f_{5m}=0$?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can answer your question. It is true that $f_n$ is periodic modulo $5$, but the period could be something ugly like $31$. The downvoter might expect you to argue that the period divides $2000$.

Comment: @barto Actually, all (but one) answers were simultaneously downvoted which seems strange. Btw, there are certainly quicker solutions since this is the extremely well-known Fibonacci sequence mod 5, but the technique is well-worth knowing anyway. (And the period can't be larger than 25.)

Comment: @mrf, I have never downvoted anyone. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/94817/sush?tab=votes&sort=downvote)

Comment: @Sush I didn't say (or think) it was you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is Fibonnacci number and $f_{5m}=0$ and $2000$ is a multiple of $5$.

Comment: Thank you. Will you please also provide the method to find $F_{2000}$?

Comment: How are we guaranteed that $f_{5m}=0$?

Comment: @Sush: I add a comment to your question. See that.